# Error with Ñ in ExecuteNonQuery with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Hello and first of all thank you for reading.
I have in a .txt file the query to execute by "ExecuteNonQuery" to verify if the tables exists, etc.

The problems come when I try to collect the "ñ" char from the .txt file and execute this in the ExecuteNonQuery (If I put the query in the SQL Server Management Studio it works).
I must use this char because of it's include in the column's name 'año' which means 'year' in English.

PD: I tried putting '&ntilde' and it works, the ExecuteNonQuery didn't give me any error, but SqlServer doesn't recognize it.

Finally, I left a small example of the SQL Query on the .txt File:

```
CREATE TABLE[dbo].[autos]( 
id_auto int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null PRIMARY KEY, 
patente varchar(7) not null, 
marca varchar(12) not null, 
modelo varchar(12) not null, 
año int not null, 
comentarios_auto varchar(200),
fecha_registro date DEFAULT GetDate() not null)
```

The code in C#:

```
 int counter = 0;
        string linea;
        string contenedor_texto;
        contenedor_texto = "";
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:/Users/Natario/Desktop/test.txt");
        while ((linea = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            contenedor_texto = contenedor_texto + linea;
            counter++;
        }
        string comando_consulta = contenedor_texto;
        comandoSQLbeta(comando_consulta,datosConexion);
```

PD2: comandoSQLbeta, only execute the SQLQuery which contains 'comando_consulta'.
PD3: The parameter 'datosConexion' is a string which contains the connectionString

Comment: Try `[año] int not null` with square brackets, and see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure the column type doesn't need to be `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Trying, i'll answer as soon as i try. 
@itsme86 Sorry for unkown. What's the difference between `nvarchar` and `varchar`?

Comment: nvarchar stores unicode text. varchar stores ASCII text.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It worked! Thank you so much!. 
Any way to mark the post as solved?

Comment: @Natarr You need to wait for 15 minutes to pass from the moment you posted the question before you can mark an answer as a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets to escape names with characters from alphabets other than Latin:

```
CREATE TABLE[dbo].[autos]( 
id_auto int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null PRIMARY KEY, 
patente varchar(7) not null, 
marca varchar(12) not null, 
modelo varchar(12) not null, 
[año] int not null, -- <<== Here
comentarios_auto varchar(200),
fecha_registro date DEFAULT GetDate() not null)
```